# A ground rod where a drain needs to go

Tags: electrical, drain, grounding

My house sits on a hill, and the gutters don't properly drain. As a result, I'm digging a new  drain along the side of the house to re-route the water.

However, while digging the drain, I came upon a grounding rod just a few inches below the surface. It's directly in the path of where I need to put the drain.

Should I re-route the drain, or try to move the grounding rod?

I should say, I do have the option to move the drain away from the house a bit, too. That might solve my problem, but the drain is doubling-up as a patio drain so it would require a fairly sharp bend to accomplish that.

Edit: sorry, not a french drain. Had french drains on the brain. Just a regular buried drain.

Comment: Can you just drive the stake farther in to the ground?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think there's enough copper wire above for me to do so. There is another grounding rod somewhere else, but I don't know where. (The wire does not terminate at the rod), so I'm not sure if I can drive it any deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really doesn't matter from a technical standpoint which choice you make, assuming all installations are done properly. Do whatever is easiest for your situation. "Proper installation" is key though, only use proper drainage ells to make turns, not vent ells, and do not add additional bends to get around obstacles that can be relocated. Also note that ground rods can be bent out of the way (or driven deeper as longneck suggests) without diminishing their effectiveness, just be careful to not damage the wire connection.

Comment: If I was doing this, I would just buy another ground rod and drive it in 1 foot away, out of the way of the drain and somewhere within range of the existing cable so you can just move it to the new rod. Then drive the existing rod further in to the ground or cut it off.

Comment: @longneck ... Genius.

Comment: If you drive a new ground rod, you'll have to have it checked to make sure it provides an adequate ground.